# How to remove nan and inf values from a numpy matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
cv = [[1,3,4,56,0,345],[2,3,2,56,87,255],[234,45,35,76,12,87]]
cv2 = [[1,6,4,56,0,345],[2,3,4,56,187,255],[234,45,35,0,12,87]]

output = np.true_divide(cv,cv2,where=(cv!=0) | (cv2!=0))
print(output)`
```

I am getting Nan and inf values.i tried to remove differently means once i removed Nan and then i removed Inf values and replace them with 0.But i need to replace them together!Is there any way to replace them together ?

Comment: "But i need to replace them together!I" Why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just replace `NaN` and infinite values with the following mask:

```
output[~np.isfinite(output)] = 0

>>> output
array([[1.        , 0.5       , 1.        , 1.        , 0.        ,
        1.        ],
       [1.        , 1.        , 0.5       , 1.        , 0.46524064,
        1.        ],
       [1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 0.        , 1.        ,
        1.        ]])
```

Comment: You don't need the `isnan`, `isfinite` checks for both: ["Test element-wise for finiteness (not infinity or not Not a Number)."](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.isfinite.html)

Answer (score 6):

There is a special function just for that:

```
numpy.nan_to_num(x_arr, copy=False, nan=0.0, posinf=0.0, neginf=0.0)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to modify the array in place, you can make use of the `np.ma` library, and create a masked array:

```
np.ma.masked_array(output, ~np.isfinite(output)).filled(0)
```

```
array([[1.        , 0.5       , 1.        , 1.        , 0.        ,
        1.        ],
       [1.        , 1.        , 0.5       , 1.        , 0.46524064,
        1.        ],
       [1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 0.        , 1.        ,
        1.        ]])
```